# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null

Tags: java

hi i'm working on a project in which i need to make changes to BASE64 string of an image(jpg)...so at first when i didn't made any changes, the ImageReader was properly working and my image was displayed properly..but when i made changes to my BASE64 string the above exception came..i searched a lot and came to know that im==null comes when ByteStream is not jpeg,png,gif..etc..so what if i have a new type of ByteStream...what should i use?? or what ever my BASE64 string is i need to convert that to an image..so how can i do that??

here is my code snippet:this is to convert [BASE64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string to an image

```
 public  static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] imageByte;
    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("d:/CopyOfTestImage.jpg"));

    return image;
   }
```

Comment: If anything goes wrong in the first part of the method, you're just keeping going, ignoring the error completely. That's the first thing to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Javadocs for ImageIO.read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29):

> Returns a `BufferedImage` as the result of decoding a supplied `InputStream` with an `ImageReader` chosen automatically from among those currently registered. The `InputStream` is wrapped in an `ImageInputStream`. **If no registered `ImageReader` claims to be able to read the resulting stream, `null` is returned**. [emphasis mine]

The read method can return `null`, yet you are not checking for this.  In fact the method *is* probably returning null, which is why `ImageIO.write` throws an exception when you pass null into it.

First things first, you need to check for error conditions and handle them appropriately (including the null return, but also including any exceptions that are thrown, which you currently catch and ignore).

Now if you're getting null back from ImageIO.read, it means the bytes you passed into the read method did not appear to be a valid image in any known format.  You need to look in more detail at the modifications you're making to the base64 string, and ensure that what you're doing is valid, and results in a valid image.  Alternatively, if you're getting some other exception thrown, then you need to handle that appropriately.

(As a general rule, don't throw away/skip over errors, because then when things go wrong you have no idea why!)

Comment: thank you for the reply Andrzej Doyle ...as i have checked,it is my read method which is creating this error...but i need to create that distorted image as my result,this is what i have to show in my work..

Comment: actually i want to show distorted results in an image and this read method of mine is not accepting its byte..so please suggest me some good ways of doing it..

Comment: There's a difference between creating a distorted image (i.e. a valid image format where the pixels have been subjected to mathematical transformations) and a **corrupted** image (where the underlying bytes have arbitrary changes).  It sounds like you're creating the latter - which, since it's not a valid image file, cannot be rendered.  Trying to create "distortions" by modfying the raw bytes (or a base64-encoded version of them) sounds like completely the wrong approach, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("d:/CopyOfTestImage.jpg"));
```

to something like this

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/CopyOfTestImage.jpg"));
```